# Why are some embedded registers password protected?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

Some registers on MSP430 devices (and I assume some non-TI chips, but I mostly know MSP430s) have "passwords" that reset the device if software writes to the register without the right password.

[image: WDT]
[image: FCTL]

Why are these registers "password" protected, and why is the recourse to reset the device rather than just ignore the write? It can't be any kind of security feature, since the key value is non-configurable and in the datasheet. There are plenty of ways to shoot yourself in the foot in C (that the MCU designer can't possibly prevent you from doing) beyond writing nonsense to peripheral registers, so I assume there's a reason beyond protecting users from themselves.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These registers have a disproportionally significant effect on the device's reliability, and likewise on the reliability of the surrounding system that the device is integrated in:

- The watchdog timer is one of a few safeguards against a badly malfunctioning program getting a device caught in an unexpected state indefinitely, since it will force a chip reset if the watchdog timer is not successfully reset before its timeout. If the timer can be reset or disabled by a write to a wayward pointer, then its protection is much weaker.
- Writing to flash incorrectly could corrupt the program and brick the product that uses the microcontroller. A wayward pointer writing to the flash control register could prevent the system from functioning even after a reboot.

Your assumption that this is not specific to TI is correct. For example, the [atmega 328](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001906A.pdf) requires a specific timed sequence to reset the watchdog:

[image]

Comment: It didn't occur to me that only the control registers for particularly important things are password-protected; I suspect I could get equally catastrophic results in many systems by messing up my unprotected SPI or GPIO settings, but I can buy that the extra protection is worth it for some things.

Comment: @Duckrubber27 Yeah, but the watchdog is meant to curb issues arising in those parts of the system so if the watchdog messes up what little measure you have are gone. Similar to nuclear power plants. A lot of the stuff that you think is really critical like reactor control doesn't actually have as much redundancy as you might think, but does is the safety system meant to shut everything down when something goes wrong.

Comment: @Duckrubber27 - Or another way to think about it - this protects against accidents and mistakes, not malice. Similar to how many programming language features are designed (think access modifiers in OOP).

Answer (score 21):

The job of the watchdog is ensuring that your software still runs, not that something that just randomly overwrites memory (e.g. a buffer overflow, or plain, an addressing bug) among many other things also happens to hit the watchdog timer "dead man's switch" once in a while.

Hence, it makes sense to specify that *if* something is written, it needs to be the right word. That way, the watchdog can serve as protection against both "hangups" as well as "random memory corruption bugs".

Answer (score 11):

Pretty much every watchdog peripheral I've ever worked with requires that an unique number sequence is written to the register on regular basis. In case you write the wrong one, the MCU will reset. The rationale is to prevent buggy/run-away code from updating the watchdog.

But this is also a *feature*: it allows the programmer a means to immediately reset the MCU instead of waiting for the watchdog timeout, by writing an incorrect sequence. In case of critical errors, the only sensible thing to do is often to reset and then you might want that reset to happen immediately.

Many watchdog peripherals also support a "window mode" where you must write to it within a fixed time interval or the MCU will reset. This is commonly used in high integrity real-time systems.

Answer (score 5):

A similar mechanism is used on newer AVRs (XMEGA and related), though not with a watchdog integrated mechanism.  The CCP (Configuration Change Protection) simply does nothing if the sequence fails.  It is used on important system registers, such as system/CPU clock, or peripherals that you might be using for hard real-time functions (like motor control).

Probably there are examples from many families; the title on this post is not specific, so it seems worth mentioning the others.

Answer (score 1):

Note something other people have not addressed: the watchdog is not a strong defense against a (very) buggy firmware. It is meant as a last ditch resort against two scenarios:

First and foremost:

some bit in the RAM has been randomly flipped by cosmic rays (or other external interference, like EM pulses) or external inputs have been messed up by excessive *unforeseen* interference. This random event makes the firmware go haywire so the best course of action is RESET.

This scenario is uncommon enough that is completely unforeseeable and cannot be coped with in other ways (if it were common, like in space probes, you would need to shield the hardware to make it a rare event, otherwise your system design is botched by definition!).

Second scenario:

You want to avoid the system halting because you have a yet *unknown* bug in your firmware that manifests so rarely that hasn't been caught by the *extensive testing* your firmware has undergone (did you do that, didn't you?). Typical cases are the so called [eisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

These are two very catastrophic scenarios, since normal system reliability countermeasures have been ineffective, therefore the last ditch is RESET.

Well, unless even that doesn't work and you have to push the self-destruct button of a multimillion-dollar space probe launcher just to avoid it hitting a city like a weapon.

Answer (score 0):

These are not just "some embedded registers", they are WatchDog Timer (WDT) registers, and the watchdog timer is the most critical part of most embedded devices, the last line of defence ensuring that that device doesn't misbehave in a way that could catastrophically affect its environment.

The addition of a password to permit writes to these registers decreases the likelihood that they can be accidentally, successfully written to by many orders of magnitude; the likelihood of a register address being corrupted to point to a watchdog register is relatively low, but the likelihood of said address being corrupted **and** the write also having the watchdog password attached is far smaller.

Essentially it's defence in depth.